# Sports vocabulary

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning, word-difference

I'm a little bit confused.
I'm trying to learn sport vocabulary but I can't understand the difference between course and court, also there are some words which meanings aren't very clear for me.For example the words like circuit,slope,track and pitch. Could you help me with this?

Comment: Have you looked them up in a dictionary? What was it that it was so confusing to you that you decided to ask this question on ELL?

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty much down to idiomatic usage for each sport.

"Course" is mainly used for races of various kinds, since "course" means a path to follow.

Tennis and basketball are played on "courts".

Some usages are even regional. Soccer is played on a "field" in the US but on "the pitch" in the UK.